# Alexa interceptor for native skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there some way to implement an interceptor (request or response) for all native skills/functions?

I would like to change "Turn nightstand on" into "Turn bedroom 1 nightstand on" or "Turn bedroom 2 nightstand on" based on the device ID of where the command is issued.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way for developers to intercept or modify Alexa 1P functions.

As an end user, you could achieve this specific use case with 2 device groups to partition your Alexa devices and smart plugs/bulbs:

Bedroom1: echo1, light1
Bedroom2: echo2, light2

Saying "Alexa, turn the light on" to either echo implicitly turns on just the light that's in the same group as the echo.

Comment: Thanks very much - that is very helpful. Do you know if there is a way for a user skill to call/execute a 1P function?